# Suppress duplicate warnings in IntelliJ IDEA by annotation

Tags: intellij-idea, suppress-warnings, code-duplication

Since version 15, [IntelliJ warns me about code duplicates](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/analyzing-duplicates.html?origin=old_help).

In some cases this might be intentional, so I want to ignore/suppress this warning by using the `@SuppressWarnings` annotation. But what is the correct value for this?

Edit: I'm not asking for disabling this kind of inspection completely as in question [Is it possible to disable duplicate code detection in Intellij?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36627002/is-it-possible-to-disable-duplicate-code-detection-in-intellij)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to disable duplicate code detection in Intellij?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36627002/is-it-possible-to-disable-duplicate-code-detection-in-intellij)

Comment: I don't think so. The linked question is about disabling this inspection completely.

Comment: For those using PyCharm: `# noinspection DuplicatedCode`

Answer (score 139, accepted):

This works for me. You have to set it on both classes/methods if you want to suppress the warning both places.

```
@SuppressWarnings("Duplicates")
private void myDuplicatedMethod() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: And I wrote it all lowercase and did not get it, thank you for clarification!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: If you want to ignore a block, not the entire method or class, then @user6658417 answer is better. Just add //noinspection Duplicates before that block.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in a .js file in IntelliJ, version 2020.1. I'm just getting another warning `Unresolved function or method SuppressWarnings()`

Answer (score 20):

Just saw this and thought I would throw this in for posterity.  To suppress for just one block rather than the whole method, you can use a line comment:

```
//noinspection Duplicates
```

(I also find it handy to do this for unchecked)
(I'm using version 2016-2, but I think this has been around awhile)

Comment: Don't get excited, You know it a bad habit to suppress 'em, right?

Comment: @AmanuelNega, if you have local test classes to try things out which are not part of the code line, you don't want them to interfere with these types of warnings anywhere else. This is an appreciated response to a valid question posted by the OP.

Comment: Apparently the comment has to be immediately before the open brace, e.g. if (...) //noinspection Duplicates { ... } -- which forces the open brace onto the next line.

Comment: @JohnVelonis, In idea 2017.3 I have added it just before if block and it works. Note: You can not put any other comment line after this.

Answer (score 18):

Thank you for all the answers. There is also another more generic approach to suppress warnings:

1. Place the cursor within the code that gives you a warning
2. Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Go to the warning entry (in this case "Navigate to duplicate")
4. Don't hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> but <kbd>→</kbd> (right arrow)
5. Now you can select some suppressing options (for class/method/statement)

[image]

Comment: Ugh, all this does is add the @SuppressWarnings annotation, which I'd rather not litter my code with.  Oh well.

Comment: Yes, this is why this qualifies as an answer to that question.

Comment: Thanks! Good to know different options exists.