# Is it possible to disable duplicate code between intellij modules?

Tags: intellij-idea

[While it is possible to disable duplicate code detection entirely,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36627002/is-it-possible-to-disable-duplicate-code-detection-in-intellij) I am looking for disabling duplicate code detection just between modules. That is, duplicate code within a module will be detected, but if I have the same file in two different modules, that will not be detected

edit: so it is not possible to do this. Intellij modules by definition are not made to do this.

Comment: Raises the question of "why have the same code in two modules", but...

Comment: My modules are more like projects. The current project is working with 30 different microservices, a lot of which rely on each other. It's just a lot easier to to have each ms in the same project pane. I haven't found a better solution to manage multiple projects within one intellij window. I've tried the multiple project windows, but it eats my RAM and I can't have all the MS's queryable at once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such option. If you have code which is duplicated between multiple microservices, you can extract it into a separate module and then link this module as a jar into the microservices that use it.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanting to re-iterate. If you are going to make a project with intellij, you should follow the intellij guidelines that each project should be separated by different windows, and not used as different modules in each.

Comment: If you have a microservice architecture with ten services, then you have ten modules in your intellij project; this should not be separated in different windows

Answer (score 0):

that problem only show in ultimate version if you can following that step you can solve that problem

Go to

```
**Setting->Inspections->General->Duplicated Code**
```

[Duplicate line case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfbzP.png)