# PyCharm Python what is noinspection tag for code duplicates

Tags: python, pycharm, suppress-warnings

I have the PyCharm inspection enabled for duplicated code fragment (Inspections --> General --> Duplicated code fragment).

I am trying to use a `noinspection` tag to locally disable this inspection in my Python code.  However, I can't figure out the noinspection tag.  It's not documented in my usual source: [pylover/inspections.txt](https://gist.github.com/pylover/7870c235867cf22817ac5b096defb768)

Does anyone know it?

---

**What I Have Tried**

Options that don't work:

- `# noinspection Duplicates`
- `//noinspection Duplicates` (this is not for Python)
- `# SuppressWarnings("Duplicates")`
- `# noinspection DuplicatedCode` (from [JetBrains YouTrack PY-38309](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-38309))

[Is it possible to disable duplicate code detection in Intellij?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36627002/is-it-possible-to-disable-duplicate-code-detection-in-intellij)

I do not want to uncheck the inspection, I just want to be able to locally suppress it.

I also tried running the command documented in [pylover/inspections.txt](https://gist.github.com/pylover/7870c235867cf22817ac5b096defb768):

```bsh
unzip -p lib/pycharm.jar com/jetbrains/python/PyBundle.properties | grep -B1 INSP.NAME | grep '^#' | sed 's|Inspection||g' | sed -e 's|#\s\{,1\}|# noinspection |'
```

And I didn't see any mentions of duplicates there.

---

**Versions**

- OS: macOS Mojave 10.14.3
- Python: 3.6.5
- PyCharm: 2020.1 PE

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you've found a solution to your problem, but `# noinspection DuplicatedCode` works for me.

---

**Versions**

- OS: macOS Monterey 12.3.1
- Python: 3.9.11
- PyCharm: 2022.1 PE

Comment: Place comment before the statement