# Exclude folder from Pycharms duplicate check

Tags: python, pycharm

Q: How do I exclude a folder from pycharm's duplicate check?

#### Minimal Example:

Say my pycharm project folder structure looks like this:

```
project/main.py
project/.backup/main_copy.py
```

How do I tell pycharm not to warn me that main.py and main_copy.py contain duplicate code?

Comment: Is the following link helpful: [Is it possible to disable duplicate code detection in Intellij?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36627002/is-it-possible-to-disable-duplicate-code-detection-in-intellij)

Comment: @Shmn unfortunately not. I only want to exclude the folder not disable duplicate checks

Comment: Does right-clicking on .backup and marking it as excluded help?

Comment: @user2235698 yes that actually worked. thanks.

Comment: @user2640045 thanks, posted as an answer

Comment: @2235698 I accepted and liked it :).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try to mark `.backup` as excluded via right-click on it -> `Mark Directory as`.