# Find all String values that can be replaced by constants (static final) with Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, constants

I'm trying to find all the places in a project where a constant could be introduced, because a String literal is being overused.

I'm aware of the Refactor > Introduce Constant... (Ctrl + Alt + C) function that Intellij has. But I can't find a way to search massively for these places where this function would make sense to be applied.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### For IntelliJ Ultimate:

- [Is it possible to disable duplicate code detection in Intellij?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36627002/is-it-possible-to-disable-duplicate-code-detection-in-intellij)

---

##### For IntelliJ Community:

By exploiting the localization (translation) feature, you can find all string duplicates... This isn't as robust as the Ultimate "duplicate code" feature -- which is capable of detecting duplicate code blocks -- but can help for quickly finding duplicates strings in a project.

**Preferences |  Editor | Inspections | Java | Internationalization | Duplicate String Literal**

- Click the checkbox to enable ☑
- Set the minimum string length value (it defaults to 5 characters)
- Change the warning level to  `Error`

Then navigate to **View | Tool Windows | Problems** and click the **Project Errors** tab.

---

##### Disclaimer

```java
String.format("This probably goes without saying, but " +
   "be weary of over engineering your code, sometimes " + 
   "%s are %s when %s", 
   STRING_LITERALS, EASIER_TO_READ, JUST_TYPED_OUT);
```